# PHP GET, use URL friendly instead of from ID?

Tags: php

I have a .txt file like this (about 200 lines)

```
Fjärilar smakar med fötterna.
Ett normalt badkar rymmer ca 200 liter.
```

With this PHP code can someone use a link like http://example.com.com/?quote=2 and they get the second quote and if they visit http://example.com.com the get a random quote. I update the URL (forward the user to the id URL) if the user gets a random do make it able to share the link and come back to the quote.

```
$f_contents = file("facts.txt");
if(!isset($_GET['quote']) || !is_numeric($_GET['quote']) || $_GET['quote'] > count($f_contents)){
    $random = array_rand($f_contents);
    $line = $f_contents[$random];
    header("Location: ?quote=$random");
    die();
}else{
    $line = $f_contents[$_GET['quote']];
}
```

How can I convert this ut to use URL friendly instead of from ID? I the user use the link http://example.com.com/?quote=fjarilar-smakar-med-fotterna. the get the first row, I also use Swedish letters in the quote.

Comment: If you want the user to be able to type anything in to the URL, it sounds like you're talking about making a searching algorithm. There are loads of those that are available as open source. Just take whatever input the user types in and search against. If you're generating a "friendly" URL for the user instead, what I usually do is hide the id in the URL, like `example.com/2/fjalrilar%20smakar%20...` Then you just use the 2 in the URL to retrieve the right quote (which you can get with an .htaccess mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a database table where for each entry of id have a column named 'friendly_url' so based on this info you can write URL rewriting rules or code to redirect the same.

Comment: I don't want to use a database. maybe I can do a comma CSV file file instead where I split with a comma?

Comment: yes any data storage you can use. Just map friendly url against each id. then use that mapping to rewrite url in code while user hit.

Answer (score 0):

### Generate slugs

First you could generate SEO friendly URL (Slugs) using the [`php-slugs`](http://code.google.com/p/php-slugs/) from Google. Here is the working version:

```
function my_str_split($string)
{
    $slen=strlen($string);
    for($i=0; $i<$slen; $i++)
    {
        $sArray[$i]=$string{$i};
    }
    return $sArray;
}

function noDiacritics($string)
{
    //cyrylic transcription
    $cyrylicFrom = array('А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я');
    $cyrylicTo   = array('A', 'B', 'W', 'G', 'D', 'Ie', 'Io', 'Z', 'Z', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'Ch', 'C', 'Tch', 'Sh', 'Shtch', '', 'Y', '', 'E', 'Iu', 'Ia', 'a', 'b', 'w', 'g', 'd', 'ie', 'io', 'z', 'z', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'ch', 'c', 'tch', 'sh', 'shtch', '', 'y', '', 'e', 'iu', 'ia'); 


    $from = array("Á", "À", "Â", "Ä", "Ă", "Ā", "Ã", "Å", "Ą", "Æ", "Ć", "Ċ", "Ĉ", "Č", "Ç", "Ď", "Đ", "Ð", "É", "È", "Ė", "Ê", "Ë", "Ě", "Ē", "Ę", "Ə", "Ġ", "Ĝ", "Ğ", "Ģ", "á", "à", "â", "ä", "ă", "ā", "ã", "å", "ą", "æ", "ć", "ċ", "ĉ", "č", "ç", "ď", "đ", "ð", "é", "è", "ė", "ê", "ë", "ě", "ē", "ę", "ə", "ġ", "ĝ", "ğ", "ģ", "Ĥ", "Ħ", "I", "Í", "Ì", "İ", "Î", "Ï", "Ī", "Į", "Ĳ", "Ĵ", "Ķ", "Ļ", "Ł", "Ń", "Ň", "Ñ", "Ņ", "Ó", "Ò", "Ô", "Ö", "Õ", "Ő", "Ø", "Ơ", "Œ", "ĥ", "ħ", "ı", "í", "ì", "i", "î", "ï", "ī", "į", "ĳ", "ĵ", "ķ", "ļ", "ł", "ń", "ň", "ñ", "ņ", "ó", "ò", "ô", "ö", "õ", "ő", "ø", "ơ", "œ", "Ŕ", "Ř", "Ś", "Ŝ", "Š", "Ş", "Ť", "Ţ", "Þ", "Ú", "Ù", "Û", "Ü", "Ŭ", "Ū", "Ů", "Ų", "Ű", "Ư", "Ŵ", "Ý", "Ŷ", "Ÿ", "Ź", "Ż", "Ž", "ŕ", "ř", "ś", "ŝ", "š", "ş", "ß", "ť", "ţ", "þ", "ú", "ù", "û", "ü", "ŭ", "ū", "ů", "ų", "ű", "ư", "ŵ", "ý", "ŷ", "ÿ", "ź", "ż", "ž");
    $to   = array("A", "A", "A", "AE", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "AE", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "a", "a", "a", "ae", "ae", "a", "a", "a", "a", "ae", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "H", "H", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "IJ", "J", "K", "L", "L", "N", "N", "N", "N", "O", "O", "O", "OE", "O", "O", "O", "O", "CE", "h", "h", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "ij", "j", "k", "l", "l", "n", "n", "n", "n", "o", "o", "o", "oe", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "R", "R", "S", "S", "S", "S", "T", "T", "T", "U", "U", "U", "UE", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "W", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z", "r", "r", "s", "s", "s", "s", "ss", "t", "t", "b", "u", "u", "u", "ue", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "w", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z");


    $from = array_merge($from, $cyrylicFrom);
    $to   = array_merge($to, $cyrylicTo);

    $newstring=str_replace($from, $to, $string);
    return $newstring;
}

function makeSlugs($string, $maxlen=0)
{
    $newStringTab=array();
    $string=strtolower(noDiacritics($string));
    if(function_exists('str_split'))
    {
        $stringTab=str_split($string);
    }
    else
    {
        $stringTab=my_str_split($string);
    }

    $numbers=array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","-");
    //$numbers=array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");

    foreach($stringTab as $letter)
    {
        if(in_array($letter, range("a", "z")) || in_array($letter, $numbers))
        {
            $newStringTab[]=$letter;
        }
        elseif($letter==" ")
        {
            $newStringTab[]="-";
        }
    }

    if(count($newStringTab))
    {
        $newString=implode($newStringTab);
        if($maxlen>0)
        {
            $newString=substr($newString, 0, $maxlen);
        }

        $newString = removeDuplicates('--', '-', $newString);
    }
    else
    {
        $newString='';
    }

    return $newString;
}


function checkSlug($sSlug)
{
    if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*$/", $sSlug) == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function removeDuplicates($sSearch, $sReplace, $sSubject)
{
    $i=0;
    do{

        $sSubject=str_replace($sSearch, $sReplace, $sSubject);
        $pos=strpos($sSubject, $sSearch);

        $i++;
        if($i>100)
        {
            die('removeDuplicates() loop error');
        }

    }while($pos!==false);

    return $sSubject;
}
```

So that if you call this:

```
echo makeSlugs("Fjärilar smakar med fötterna.");
```

The output will be:

```
fjaerilar-smakar-med-foetterna
```

### Use them to redirect to your quote

Of course you cannot have the quote just by url, you must have a dictionary in which you can parse the slug into the correct quote, or, as already mentioned in another answer, keep track of the slugs onto a database.

#### OR

I used to do this way: use a combination of slugs and ids together, for example your new url would be: https://example.com/?quote=fjaerilar-smakar-med-foetterna.1

Then you can split the slug and get the second part, which is the `id`, and redirect the user to the correct quote.

```
$url = "fjaerilar-smakar-med-foetterna.1"; // $_GET['quote'];
$split = explode(".", $url);
echo $split[1];
```

Output:

```
1
```

Of course users will be able to write anything before the `id`, but that's not the point. The important thing is that the user will be able to share the quote with a friendly URL. This method is being used by many CMS.